# Webpack: error during npm start

Tags: webpack

I'm facing a problem with package.json, I will also post the image of the cmd error which I'm getting. Problem is webpack.config.js create the src and dist files but npm start won't work.

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some basic ReactJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-
              dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src/index.html dist/index.html"
   },
"keywords": [
  "reactjs"
 ],
 "author": "Maximilian Schwarzmueller",
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.2.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.2.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.11.0",
  "webpack": "^1.13.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
 }
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
Hash: e515b3cecad65c29e67e
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 2325ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  1.66 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  1.59 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && copy src/index.html 
dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script 'webpack -d && copy 
src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --
inline --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-
dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\akhan5\Desktop\test3\reactjs-basics\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\akhan5\Desktop\test3\reactjs-basics\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `start` script only calls `npm build`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build"
```

and "npm build" does this:

```
"build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot"
```

Basically, npm start would never work because it would start building the project again, for helping you on why your `build` script is broken, i would need your `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```